How to Create a Multi-Page Contact Form Mimicking Google’s New Login Page?
I'm trying to create a multi-page contact form that mimics the flow of Google’s new login page. Here’s what I'm aiming for:

First Page: Similar to Google's initial sign-in page where the user enters their email.

Second Page: After entering the email, it should:

Display the entered email

Show a generic profile picture

Have fields for the subject and message



Third Page: Shows a "Message Sent" confirmation.


I’m looking for guidance on how to achieve the multi-page slide effect and the smooth transitions between each page. Any advice on the following would be highly appreciated:

How to structure the HTML/CSS for this?

Best practices for handling the transitions (JavaScript or any specific libraries)?

How to ensure data validation across the pages before submission?

Example code snippets would be extremely helpful!


What did you try and what were you expecting?
I started by creating a basic HTML form to capture email, subject, and message fields. I also attempted to use simple CSS for styling and JavaScript for page transitions. I expected it to smoothly transition between pages and validate the input data. However, I ran into issues with the transitions not being smooth and difficulty in maintaining the form state across pages.

Those aren't "pages". Google uses Javascript and a technique called AJAX to communicate with the server and change the content of the page. You can find this out by using the developer tools of your browser. Try to learn more about AJAX. You need to learn to walk before you can run.

I understand that, but I was hoping I could get away with just JavaScript and CSS, as it's a contact form, not a sign-in page. But thank you for being so helpful in pointing out the obvious.

I'm afraid SO isn't an ab inito coding service. If you have a problem with some code please post it in your question with a specific query describing what you need to be resolved.

I don’t really understand why there have to be different pages. Could this not be just one page where parts are not displayed until they need to be?

It could be something like this, where I divide up the form in three fieldsets, and then make the fieldsets visible when going to the next fieldset.
I use the build-in form validation to enable the buttons, like when you enter an email, it must be a valid email before you can go to the next step.


const form = document.forms.contact;

display_slide('slide1');

form.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case 'next':
      let next_id = parseInt(fieldset.dataset.id) + 1;
      display_slide(`slide${next_id}`);
      break;
  }
});

form.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
  // test the fieldset for validity
  let invalid = !![...fieldset.elements].filter(elm => !elm.validity.valid).length;
  if(fieldset.elements.next) fieldset.elements.next.disabled = invalid;
  // test the form for validity
  let formvalid = form.checkValidity();
  form.submitbtn.disabled = !formvalid;
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case 'email':
      form.emailoutput.value = e.target.value;
      break;
  }
});

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  // faking the POST URL with a data URI
  fetch('data:application/json,{"status":"ok"}', {
  //fetch('contact.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json.status == 'ok') {
        display_slide('slide3');
      }
    });
});

function display_slide(name) {
  [...form.elements]
  .filter(elm => elm.type == 'fieldset')
    .forEach(fieldset => fieldset.classList.add('hidden'));
  form[name].classList.remove('hidden');
}
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  width: 450px;
}

fieldset {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
}

fieldset.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

fieldset .form {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: left .5s;
}

fieldset.hidden .form {
  left: 300px;
}
<main>
  <form name="contact">
    <fieldset data-id="1" name="slide1">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Contact form</h3>
        <p>Enter your email address</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <label>Email: <input type="email" name="email" required></label>
        <button type="button" name="next" disabled>Next</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-id="1" name="slide2">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Contact form</h3>
        <p>Enter a subject and message</p>
        <p>From: <output name="emailoutput"></output></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <label>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" required></label>
        <label>Message: <textarea name="message" required></textarea></label>
        <button type="submit" name="submitbtn" disabled>Send</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-id="1" name="slide3">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Contact form</h3>
        <p>The message as been send</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <p>✅</p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>




I don't understand why Jamie Hooper hasn't reacted to your answer yet. It does almost exactly what was asked for.

thank you that helps so much your a star

I built it with react https://contact.jamieparishooper.com
